# filter the html table data using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

```
<table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr><th> Block</th>
                    <th>Size</th></tr>

                </thead>
                <tbody id="poolTable" class="tbody">
                <tr>
                    <td>78</td>
                    <td>18</td>

               </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>52</td>
                    <td>21</td>

               </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>54</td>
                    <td>19</td>
                  </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Hi, I want to filter the html table data by using jquery, 
   can anyone try to resolve this please!!

Comment: and what is your question??

Comment: people should not write your solution, you should write what you have tried and what is your problem and people will help you

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please Update it.

Comment: <input type="text" id="filter" placeholder="Filter" /> 
            <button id="btnFilter" class="btn btn-success">Go</button>
script as
$('#btnFilter').click(function(){

       var x = $('#filter').val();

       console.log(x);

   });

Comment: How you imagine this would work? What should I insert intoo input with id="filter"?

Comment: You want to add search functionality in table?

Comment: ya, I want to add filter option to the table

Answer (score 1):

Please try bellow JavaScript for to get content of each td

```
$("#filter").keyup(function(){
    var filter = $(this).val();
    $("#poolTable > tr").each(function(e){

        cells = this.cells;
        for(i=0; i< cells.length; i++){
           alert(cells[i].innerHTML);
        }

    });
})
```

Comment: It does not do such thing

Comment: what can be the value of lenght in this case

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

https://sunnywalker.github.io/jQuery.FilterTable/

It is a jQuery plugin that will allow you to filter your table.

Answer (score 0):

```
function filter(){
    var text = $('#search').val();

    $('#poolTable tr').show();
    if (text != "")  {
        $('#poolTable tr td.number').each(function() {
            if ($(this).text().indexOf(text) >= 0) {
               $(this).parent().show();
               return true;
            } else {
               $(this).parent().hide();
            }
        });
```

This works. Here number is the class name of `td`. It only filters the single column.